# PHP scripts execute stops after a while with no error report

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, wampserver

i have a crawler script that run 4 bots Simultaneously,
each bot is opened in a new tab and generally does that:

1/ connection to db + set vars that are needed for the scraping.
2/ takes a URL target from db.
3/ get the content using CURL OR file_get_content.
4/ set the "$html" with simple_html_dom.
5/ include an "engine" that scrapes and manipulate the content.
6/ finally - check if its OK and optimize the content and store it in the db
7/ do it for X links. after the X links will refresh the page and continue the crawling process.

every thing worked like magic! but lately after a few minutes (not the same time) all the bots are 
stopped (with no errors flashed) some times only 3 of them... 
there is a script that set time interval that refresh the page every Y minutes. that is keepig my
 bots working if they are jammed but its not an answer for this problem.

i have checked the apache error log and its not indicating anything strange.

do you have any idea???
shrink code: (with comments)

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include ("peulot/stations1.php");//with connection and vars
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

//DEFINE VALUES:
/*
here vars are declared and set
*/

        echo "
            <script language=javascript>

            var int=self.setInterval(function(){ refresh2(); },".$protect.");

            var counter;

            function refresh2() { 
                geti();
                link = 'store_url_beta.php?limit_link=".$limit_link."&storage_much=".$dowhile."&jammed=".($jammed_count+=1)."&bot=".$sbot."&counter=';
                link = link+counter;
                window.location=link;
                } 

            function changecolor(answer)
                    {
                document.getElementById(answer).style.backgroundColor = \"#00FF00\";
                    }
            </script>";//this is the refresh if jammed


//some functions:
/*
function utf8_encode_deep --> for encoding
function hexbin --> for simhash fingerprint
function Charikar_SimHash --> for simhash fingerprint
function SimHashfingerprint --> for simhash fingerprint
*/              

        while ($i<=$dowhile)
            {

            //final values after crawling:
            $link_insert="";
            $p_ele_insert="";
            $title_insert="";
            $alt_insert="";
            $h_insert="";
            $charset="";
            $text="";
            $result_key="";
            $result_desc="";
            $note="";

            ///this connection is to check that there are links to crawl in data base... + grab the line for crawl.
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table2 WHERE crawl='notyet' AND flag_avoid $regex $bot_action";
            $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql); 
            $idr = mysql_fetch_array($rs_result);                           
            unset ($sql);
            unset ($rs_result);

              set_time_limit(0);

              $qwe++;

                    $target_url = $idr['live_link'];//set the link we are about to crawl now.
                    $matches_relate = $idr['relate'];//to insert at last
                    $linkid = $idr['id'];//link id to mark it as crawled in the end
                    $crawl_status = $idr['crawl'];//saving this to check if we update storage table or insert new row
                    $bybot_status = $idr['by_bot'];//saving this to check if we update storage table or insert new row

                    $status ="UPDATE $table2 SET crawl='working', by_bot='".$bot."', flag_avoid='$stat' WHERE id='$linkid'";
                    if(!mysql_query($status)) die('problem15');                 

                    $ch = curl_init(); 

                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5'); 
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url); 
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

                    $str = curl_exec($ch); 
                    curl_close($ch);

                    if (strlen($str)<100) 
                            {
                            //do it with file get content
                            }               
        if (strlen($html)>500)
        {

                            require("engine.php");//GENERATE FATAL ERROR IF CRAWLER ENGINE AND PARSER NOT AVAILABLE

                        flush();//that will flush a result without any refresh
                        usleep(300);                                

                                //before inserting into table storage check if it was crawled before and then decide if to insert or update:
                                if ($crawl_status=="notyet"&&$bybot_status=="notstored")
                                            {
                                            //insert values
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                            //update values
                                            }

                        flush();//that will flush a result without any refresh
                        usleep(300);


                        if ($qwe>=$refresh) //for page refresh call
                            { 
                            $secounter++;//counter for session
                            //optimize data                         
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>function refresh() { window.location='store_url_beta.php?limit_link=".$limit_link."&counter=".$i."&secounter=".$secounter."&storage_much=".$dowhile."&jammed=".$jammed."&bot=".$sbot."'; } refresh(); </script>";                          
                            }
            }//end of if html is no empty.
            else
            {//mark a flag @4 and write title jammed!

            //here - will update the table and note that its not possible to crawl

                        if ($qwe>=$refresh) 
                            { 
                            $secounter++;//counter for session
                            //optimize data                         
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>function refresh() { window.location='store_url_beta.php?limit_link=".$limit_link."&counter=".$i."&secounter=".$secounter."&storage_much=".$dowhile."&jammed=".$jammed."&bot=".$sbot."'; } refresh(); </script>";                          

                            }
            }//end of else cant grab nothing
            unset($html);
        }//end of do while
            mysql_close(); 
            echo "<script language=javascript> window.clearInterval(int); </script>";
```

**Edit:**
after endless testing and logging methods (following jack advice) i found nothing! 
the only thing that happens when the bots are stopped is in the apache log:

```
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:33 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
 zend_mm_heap corrupted
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 1 -- Restarting.
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.3.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [notice] Server built: May 13 2012 19:41:17
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 736
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [notice] Child 736: Child process is running
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [notice] Child 736: Acquired the start mutex.
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [notice] Child 736: Starting 200 worker threads.
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [notice] Child 736: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [notice] Child 736: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
 [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
```

**this line is mysterious i really dont know what to do please help me!** 
     [Thu Oct 25 01:01:51 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 1 -- Restarting.

Comment: what a mess. please indent your code correctly.

Comment: that is a lot of code you are expecting people to wade through to give you an answer.  You should try debugging it yourself first to see if you can narrow down where the problem might be.

Comment: No one, can read all this, and help you. please show only the relevant part of your code. Also, you have so many `echo` all over your code, how about you use a template? it will make things much easier and more organized. Don't forget that you can simply close your php tag `?> and write content.

Comment: i know its not elegant but im will arrange everything once it will work,

Comment: i really think the problem is with the apache configuration i dont think the code is the reason because it doesnt generate any error.

Comment: Apache would log an error if a module had a problem, and PHP is just another module. Increase the memory allocated to PHP in the PHP.ini

Answer (score 0):

The way to find these problems usually comes down to plain old logging.

You should make each worker write entries into their own log file before and after a potentially long operation, consisting of a debug message, line number, memory usage, whatever you need to know; let it jam a few times and analyze the logs.

If there's a pattern (i.e. the logs stop showing data at the same point) you can narrow the search; if not, you might be dealing with memory issues or other fatal crashes.

It also helps to retrace what you might have changed in your setup recently, even if it seems unrelated.

Comment: thank you for your fast response! i checked again the apache log and it says alot but no errors the only one is this:[error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico

Comment: added recently these configuration to the httpd: 
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 2000
MaxRequestsPerChild 2000
KeepAliveTimeout 350
HostnameLookups off

Comment: @user1769877 I don't think I've made myself clear enough; *you* have to do the logging.

Comment: jack please check the edit i did what you suggested- and the only error i can find is on the apache log the script run with no problem.

Comment: The zend_mm heap corruption message fits the bill of a crash. Perhaps the PHP.net community can help you further with that.